# making two scripts work together for a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, css

i have this HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("shipping-method").onchange = function(){
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    };
};
</script>
<script>
function calc() {
var subtotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("subtotal").innerHTML.substring(1));
var shipping = parseInt(document.getElementById("shipping-method").value);
if(shipping == 1) {
    var total = subtotal+6.95;
    document.getElementById("shipping").innerHTML = "$"+6.95;
} else {
    var total = subtotal+17.95;
    document.getElementById("shipping").innerHTML = "$"+17.95;
}
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "$"+total;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select  onchange="calc()" class="shipping-method" id="shipping-method">
<option value="">-Choose a shipping method-</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">normal shipping - $6.95</option>
<option value="2">Priority Shipping - $17.95</option>

</select>
<div class="calculations">
<table>

<tbody><tr>
    <td>Subtotal:</td>
    <td id="subtotal">$97.00</td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td>Shipping:</td>
    <td id="shipping">$6.95</td>
</tr>



<tr class="total">
    <td>Total:</td>
    <td id="total">$103.95</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the dropdown menu is at the bottom of a webpage, so i use the first script to to get the user to the top of the page after selecting one of the options and getting the total, but both scripts don't work together, i have to remove one of them for the other to work, how to make both scripts work together without any conflict, thanks.

Comment: What is not working? And what do you mean by 2 scripts? The onload function and the calc function?

Comment: @styfle yeas, i mean the onload function and the calc function, the calc function don't work with the onload function.

Comment: @styfle i have to delete onload function for the calc function to work.

Comment: See my answer. The onload function is a single function. Assigning it twice will override it (just like a variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the onchange function. If you want to do two things, then put them both in the onchange function, don't assign it twice.

Here is some example code (shorted for brevity).

```
<html>
<head><title>Example</title></head>
<body>
<select id="shipping-method"></select>
<table></table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calc() {
        // do calculations here
    }
    document.getElementById("shipping-method").onchange = function(){
        window.scrollTo(0, 0); // scroll to top
        calc(); // call function
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I put the javascript at the bottom to avoid accessing an element that does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Try sticking this:

```
function calc() {
var subtotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("subtotal").innerHTML.substring(1));
var shipping = parseInt(document.getElementById("shipping-method").value);
if(shipping == 1) {
    var total = subtotal+6.95;
    document.getElementById("shipping").innerHTML = "$"+6.95;
} else {
    var total = subtotal+17.95;
    document.getElementById("shipping").innerHTML = "$"+17.95;
}
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "$"+total;
}
```

just before the function at the top:

```
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("shipping-method").onchange = function(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
};
```